# append() method of J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui, cldc

We know that in Java when a method returns a value we have to store that value in a variable of that type.

For example the getString() returns String and we store that value in a String variable.

In J2ME I was trying to create radio-buttons i.e. using the `ChoiceGroup` class.

```
ChoiceGroup radio;
radio=new ChoiceGroup("Select your Color",Choice.EXCLUSIVE);
radio.append("Red",null);
radio.append("White",null);
radio.append("Green",null);
```

In book the signature of append() method is

```
int append(String string, Image img)
```

I want to ask that even though I am not storing the integer value returned from the append() method my code runs perfectly.

I am using Wireless toolkit 2.5.2

Note the book has not given any reasons for this and that's why I asked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We know that in Java when a method returns a value we have to store that value in a variable of that type.

Every part of that sentence is false.
You should get a better book.

Comment: You mean to say after calling the method getString(); it is upto the programmer to store that returned String?

Comment: @R122: Yes.  For methods like `getString()` that don't do anything other than return a value, you will probably want to store the return value (otherwise, the call would be useless).  For methods like `append()` that change things, there is frequently no reason to store the returned value value (unless you actually want it).

Answer (score 3):

ChoiceGroup `append` method returns the assigned index of the element. If you don't intend to use it, it's OK to ignore returned value.

Method signature - return value and parameters have meaning clearly defined in [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/ChoiceGroup.html#append%28java.lang.String,%20javax.microedition.lcdui.Image%29):

```
public int append(String stringPart,
              Image imagePart)

Appends an element to the ChoiceGroup.

Specified by:
    append in interface Choice

Parameters:
    stringPart - the string part of the element to be added
    imagePart - the image part of the element to be added,
              or null if there is no image part 
Returns:
    the assigned index of the element 
Throws:
    NullPointerException - if stringPart is null
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the return value then you store in a variable or object.If you dont want then leave it .Its not a mistake in java